# Is it possible to set the system proxy from golang app in macOS or Linux distributes?

Tags: linux, macos, go, unix, proxy

I'm creating golang app with a proxy server as a pet project, and I want to have the possibility to set himself as a system proxy. Is it possible? And how?

Answer (score 2):

Proxies are often configured through the `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY` and `NO_PROXY` environment variables. In Unix-style operating systems, these variables are inherited from the parent process to its child processes.

This being said:

- your program can modify its own environment and start other processes as child processes (passing in the `_PROXY` variables).
- your program may modify the shell startup scripts (like `.bashrc`, `.cshrc`), and a newly started shell will pick the values up and pass them to newly started processes.

But I am not aware that modifying the environment of other (active) processes is possible.